# Javascript: Download and interact with another page

Tags: javascript, libraries

I want to do some basic scripting and I'm trying to do it in javascript. I want to basically download a wikiquote page and scrape it.

What's the best way to do this? How do I get the page? I tried to do it via jQuery.get()

```
$.get('http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words', function(data) { console.log(data); })
```

But the log is simply some error object and the console displays

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words.
>   Origin null is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
>   en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words
>
> GET http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words
>   undefined (undefined)

So I guess I'm not taking the correct approach. What should I be doing?

Also, once I DO download the file, what tools are available for me to traverse it? XPath? RegEx? Is there a way to generate a DOM model from it and attach jquery?

An interesting possibility would be to somehow just open a tiny pop-up which downloads the page and then run my script to scrape the page and return data. I am aware this sounds lot like script injection. Is it even possible to do this in a friendly manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are limiting yourself to JavaScript running in the browser, and documents that are not on the same host as the page running the script — you can't.

The [Same Origin security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) makes this impossible. Without it a webpage could request data from any site (including LAN sites) that the user can access, with their ip address, their cookies, and anything else that might be used for authentication. (All your banking are belong to us).

Comment: This is interesting and I kind of want to hack up a library to get around this...

Answer (score 3):

[WikiQuote exposes an API](http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php).  You can use JSONP to make a request to the API and get the data all pre-parsed and ready to go:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).src = 
    "http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Last_words" +
        "&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=json&callback=handleQuote";

function handleQuote(quote)
{
    // quote is the response from wikiquote
}
```

Note that the response is returned as wiki markup, not html.  <strike>You'll have to do some parsing to get html, if that's what you're after.</strike>  **Edit:**  Use `action=parse&page=Last_words` to get html.

You can preview the JSON response in your browser by changing the `format` argument from `json` to `jsonfm` and paste it in your browser:

**Wiki markup:**
http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Last_words&prop=revisions&rvlimit=1&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&callback=handleQuote

**HTML:**
http://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Last_words&format=jsonfm&callback=handleQuote

**Edit:**  I really only answered half (or less) of your question.  As for how to interact with the data once you've got it, jQuery makes it simple.  If you pass an html string into `$()`, jQuery constructs the elements for you.  Then, you can access it via jQuery or DOM methods:

```
var paragraphs = $(someHTML).find("p");
```

A simple way to get the HTML from any domain via JavaScript, is to make your ajax request to a local server page that requests the document for you.  You could write a generic handler ashx page, with something like:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string url = Request.QueryString["url"];
    if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
    {
        context.Response.Write(new WebClient().DownloadString(url));
    }
}
```

And then call it with jQuery:

```
var url = encodeURIComponent("http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words");
$.get("fetch.ashx?url=" + url, function (response)
{
    var $response = $(response);
});
```

**Edit:** Newer browsers do support some cross-domain data retrieval through JavaScript by implementing [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).  FireFox and Chrome support CORS via `XMLHttpRequest`.  IE8 and IE9 support CORS with [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28VS.85%29.aspx).  The catch is that the server also has to support CORS.  In short, the server must include a response header of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` in order for the client to process the response.  And sadly, it appears wikiquote is not sending that header in its response.  Here's a [hefty article on the internals of CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control).

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have looked for the API, it didn't even occur to me. Still I'd like to know how to download files via scripts.

Comment: @George - Besides JSONP, there's no getting around the same origin security policy.  But you can easily create a server page to request the content and then make the JavaScript request through your server page: `$.get('fetch.ashx?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Last_words'), function (data) { });`

Comment: Sure this is just in the interest of scripting in general. If I cared to do it server-side a ruby or powershell script would do just fine. I suppose I could load up a tiny little iframe and parse it

Comment: @George - Nope.  IFrame's are restricted by the same origin policy.  Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/28/explaining-same-origin-policy-part-1-deny-read.aspx) that does a decent job of explaining what you can and can't do with content from another origin.

Comment: @George - I learned something new about Cross Domain data access from JavaScript, so I updated my answer.

Comment: @gilly3 - Yup, here is another good one: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ He actually makes the point that its not really newer browsers at all anymore, it's just IE6 that doesn't have it and I'd wager that if you're coding for IE6 users you're probably not coding public-facing apps so this is less likely to be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`XMLHttpRequest` cannot be used for cross-domain requests. You could load the page using an `iframe` and try to get the details from there, but i recommend to do this server-side (using a DOM or SAX parser, to answer your other question) since doing it in JavaScript is clearly not very elegant.

Comment: Hmm ok, kind of surprised at this